# What should be passed into a :(NSString *)text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Feeling a little confused. I am trying to pass a NSString as an argument to this method

-(void) setRightLabelText:(NSString *)text 
   {
    rightLabel.text = text;
   }

The code i use to call the method

```
for(int index=0; index<5; index++)
{
    NSNumber *num = [card.statsArray objectAtIndex:index];

    StatView *statView = (StatView *)[self.frontView viewWithTag:10+index];
    NSString *nameHolder = @"test";
    [statView setRightLabelText:nameHolder];
}
```

The code I used to create the View :

```
for(int i=0; i<totalButtons; i++) 
{       
    StatView *sv = [[StatView alloc] initWithYPos:ypos];
    sv.tag = 100 + i;
    [sv.overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(statTapped:)  
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    sv.overlayButton.tag = 10 + i;
    [self.frontView addSubview:sv];
    ypos += 26;
}
```

This to me looks perfect, but i get a crash when I get to this method call in the app.
Error Msg :
-[UIButton setRightLabelText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d116e0
2010-09-13 11:39:44.761 LeinsterRugby[1387:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setRightLabelText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d116e0'

Comment: what is rightLabel? is it a UIButton like it says in your error message?

Comment: @interface StatView : UIView {
@private 
 UILabel *leftLabel;
 UILabel *rightLabel;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StatView *statView = (StatView *)[self.frontView viewWithTag:10+index];` returns an `UIButton` instead of a `StatView` because the tag matches the one you assign to the button with `sv.overlayButton.tag = 10 + i;`.

Comment: You are right tob. Thanks very much. I really should have noticed that. Thanks everybody for the help

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're sending the `setRightLabelText` message (selector) to an instance of `UIButton` rather than an object of the type that you're implementing.

Rather than:

```
[statView setRightLabelText:nameHolder];
```

Do you perhaps mean:

```
[self setRightLabelText:nameHolder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason for the crash would be

```
StatView *statView = (StatView *)[self.frontView viewWithTag:10+index];
```

Your computation to get the StatView from (10+index) is wrong.
Calculate your index properly.